# Outline a TextView in a GridView on touch?

Tags: android, gridview, textview, ontouchlistener

I have a basic `GridView` set up that contains simple `TextView`s. I noticed when I run the app on a 2.3.7 device when I tap a `TextView` it gets stroked/outlined in a thick orange color. But when I run the app on a 4.3 device, nothing is changed in the UI to indicate it's being touched. Why is that?

How can I implement a stroke upon touch for all APIs greater than and including 10 - override the orange color in 2.3.7 and display the same stroke for 4.3?

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by using this property `android:listSelector`
use this for transparent effect

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```

or if you  want to add custom color effect then try like

```
android:listSelector="#00343434"
```

chose any color you like

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I set that on the GridView it highlights all of the grid upon touch. If I set it for the TextView, I see the default orange color.

Comment: @MSGadag Setting the text view background to transparent results in the entire grid view being colored upon tapping one text view. I want just the text view that was tapped to be outlined.

Comment: is that background is image or selector xml?

Comment: @MSGadag The text view currently has a background drawable. It's a solid color with a radius to make it a rounded rect. The grid view has no background.

Answer (score 0):

i think u need to create 2 **drawable xmls** to change the focus of the `textview`.

check this out. hope it helps

http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/tips/Android-EditText-focus-border-color.htm